# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have created a new column in my database through a migration as below :

```
public function up(){
  Schema::table('complains', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->integer('user_id')->after('id');
   });
}
```

When I fill in my form to post data into the database, I get the error below :

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `complains` (`title`, `body`, `name`, `regnumber`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Testing user id, Testing user id, John, cs-282-2145/2010, 2017-06-08 18:47:53, 2017-06-08 18:47:53))

How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to add `user_id` when creating a record in `complains` table.

Comment: The user_id is a foreign key, like the id field it should populate automatically when I post data into the database.

Comment: It depends on how are you trying to insert the data. You didn't show any code.

Comment: I am new on this forum, I have tried to post code on this section but, I get a message the code is too long. Anyway, I have inserted the (->nullable()) function and run the migration but I got this error: SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'user_id'

Comment: Adding nullable will not solve your problem since you want to tie a new complaint to a specific user.

Comment: what will solve my problem?

Comment: I've told you that you need to specify `user_id` in the first comment. If you don't know how to do it, you should show the code you use.

Comment: Check out the code I have shared.

Comment: Are you sure there is a logged in user? You can check this with `dd(auth()->check())`

Comment: yes, I am sure there is a logged in user since I am filling my form in the user's account.

Comment: What does `dd(auth()->check())` show?

Comment: when I insert dd(auth)->check()), I still get SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `complains` (`title`, `body`, `name`, `regnumber`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Testing user id, Complain, John, cs-282-2145/2010, 2017-06-08 19:29:23, 2017-06-08 19:29:23))

Comment: `dd()` should be used in the beginning of the method, before any other actions.

Comment: That is where I used it.

Comment: If you've used the method in the beginning of the method and you get the error, you've placed it in a wrong method.

Comment: I posted my controller, could you please show me where I should insert the line of code?

Comment: I don't see your app, so I can't be 100% sure if you use correct controller and method. But in this controller, you should put `dd()` right in the beginning of the `store` method.

Comment: public function store(Request $request)
    {
        dd(auth()->check());
        $this->validate($request, array() ....

Comment: If you still get SQLSTATE error with this code, your app uses another controller/method when you submit the form.

Comment: Sorry, I was using the dd in the wrong controller. dd returns true..

Comment: Then just fix your code so the app would use the correct controller method. `store()` method you've shown looks fine.

Comment: My apologies, I added this line of code : $complain->user_id = Auth::user()->id; in the right controller and it is working now. Thanks for your effort to help.

Answer (score 4):

I've had a similar issue with User registration today and I was getting a

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'password' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users`

I fixed it by adding password to my protected $fillable array and it worked

`protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you aren't sending a value for `user_id`

Other possibility, yout can "transform" the column `user_id` **nullable**

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for my controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Complain;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Session;
use Auth;

class ComplainController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('home');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, array(

            'title' => 'required|max:255',
            'body' => 'required'

            ));

        $complain = new Complain;

        $complain->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

        $complain->title = $request->title;
        $complain->body = $request->body;

        $complain->save();

        Session::flash('success', 'Your complain was sent to the operator, please wait for feedback.');

        return redirect::back();
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $complain = Complain::find($id);
        return view('admin')->withPost($complain);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

This is my model :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Complain extends Model
{

}
```